# Can't access the database table after I rename it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created my table as `BE Electrical`. Later changed it's name to `Be Electrical First`. Now I can't 
     access  What went wrong?

[image: Here I created the table and rename it]the table.

Comment: What exactly did you run after renaming the table? Also, it's a good practice to not use spaces in table names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of renaming your table has rendered its metadata useless

Use this for renaming

```
exec sp_rename 'Be Electrical','Be Electrical First'
```

instead of

```
exec sp_rename '[Be Electrical]','[Be Electrical First]'
```

After that you can use the table as intended.

For the current table that you have renamed you have to use the select query like

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[[Be Electrical First]]]
```

Note: try to avoid spaces in naming conventions in SQL server.